# How do I remove jar filename before endpoint's url?

Tags: java, payara, payara-micro

When I compile my maven-based project I have the resulting jar file in 'target/my-application'. When I run locally my application (I use `Payara Micro` if this is important) I have the following in log:

```
Payara Micro URLs
http://localhost:8080/my-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

How do I get rid of `my-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT` from URL address?

**As per request, I'd say that:**

> What type of application is that? EAR/WAR?

`war` application (however, maven creates for me "payara-uber-jar"
   and I run the application via `java -jar filename.jar`

> What application server is it running on?

Payara micro

> Are you using maven?

Yes, I am.

Comment: That depends on where and how you're deploying it. It also depends on the packaging type... So more info is needed in the question

Comment: Could you give me a link to all the info I should post?

Comment: What type of application is that? EAR/WAR? What application server is it running on? Are you using maven? Answers to these questions can lead to a precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello according to Paraya documentation what you need to do is:

java -jar payara-micro.jar --deploy  NAMETHATYOUWANT.war

And then the context path will be /NAMETHATYOUWANT

https://www.davidsalter.co.uk/payara-micro-context-path/